# How can I completely remove the LVM setting on a hard drive, and verify that?

Tags: lvm

On a hard drive with LVs and PVs under LVM, I would like to use `parted` to create partitions and then to use `mkfs.ext4` to create filesystems on partitions, without LVM.

Before being able to use `parted`, do I have to completely remove the LVM setting on a hard drive? What steps are to remove it?

- First remove each logical volume, by `lvdisplay` and `lvremove`.
- Then remove each volume group, by `vgdisplay` and `vgremove`.
- Then remove each physical volume, by `pvdisplay` and `pvremove`?

How can I verify if I have completed remove LVM on a hard drive?

Comment: Are the logical volumes in use on the machine? Do you care about the data that they contain?

Comment: They are not and I don't

Comment: If you don't care about the data on the hard drive just make them mkpart ext4.  see the man pages for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the vgs command and see if your disk is returned as part of a volume group, just to verify. If not then you can just go ahead and format it. If you're going to change the partition it may warn you that it's part of a volume group, and you can just ignore that.

If it is showing as an activated LVM, then be sure to vgchange -an  to deactive it before doing your lvremove, vgremove, pvremove so that it's cleanly removed from the system.

Comment: Are vgs and vgdisplay same?

Comment: vgdisplay doesn't show you the physical volumes unless you use add flags for more verbose output, vgs is a short concise list of your pvs, vgs, and space allocated.